# Is "can't" a euphemism or is it ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity, euphemisms

People often say **can't** to mean **won't**.  I am not referring to lying, but in cases where it is very clear to the listener that the speaker intends to mean **won't**.  For example: *I can't continue in this relationship.*

Similarly, people often use **can't** to mean *You should not* or *I will not allow you to*.  For example: *You can't embarrass me in public*.

Is this simply a case where **can't** is being used as a euphemism?  Or is there some subtle ambiguity in the actual meaning of the word **can / can't**?

Answer (score 20):

Neither. As I see it, it's just implied context that's omitted.

For instance, "I can't continue in this relationship" means something like "I can't continue in this relationship without significant loss to myself" or "I can't comfortably continue in this relationship", and this extra context is taken for granted. Similarly, "You can't embarrass me in public" = "You can't embarrass me in public [without inviting my disapproval]". Consider, say, "I can't jump off the tenth floor" where one does not usually bother to say "I can't jump off the tenth floor *without dying*".

It's not "I won't", but really a *qualified* "I can't" -- it's *infeasible*, or *impossible under reasonable constraints*.

Comment: +1. It also adds emphasis to what the person's saying. "You *can't* embarrass me in public" is much more forceful-sounding than "You *shouldn't* embarrass me in public."

Comment: This is exactly the same thing as `need`. I *need* to discontinue this relationship [or I would encounter significant loss.] I can't hold my breath for 20 minutes. I *need* to breath [or I will suffocate.] ((Sorry, I'm bad at examples.))

Answer (score 9):

The primary uses of *can* are to express possibility and ability, with permission a third. *Will* expresses chiefly prediction and secondly volition. *Should* expresses mainly obligation, secondarily deduction and thirdly unreal and tentative meanings.

In your first example, the speaker uses *can’t* to express inability to continue in the relationship. We don’t know the reasons behind this inability, but they are clearly of an overriding, and presumably emotional, nature. Had the speaker said *I won’t continue in this relationship* we would have gained the impression that the emotional wherewithal was present but that other reasons had prevented the continuation of the hitherto happy state of affairs. In practice, *I won’t continue in this relationship* is likely to be followed by a clause beginning with, for example, *unless* . . .

If a speaker says *You can't embarrass me in public*, the implication is that the person addressed is unable to embarrass the speaker in public without certain consequences ensuing.